# User ID in kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, uid

I'm trying to intercept the clone system call so that I could print user ID and process ID before the actual system call executes. I am using `get_user_id()->uid` to access user ID in kernel module but it returns user ID in `kuid_t` type, which I can not cast to `int`. Is there any other way to do this?

I've read about using `getuid()` (from `unistd.h`) in other forums but interestingly the compiler recognizes the  first use of this function as an *implicit declaration*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That struct is defined in `include/linux/uidgid.h`. The only thing it contains is a `val` member of type `uid_t`, which is what the userspace `getuid` returns (an `unsigned int` on Linux, follow the headers by browsing via [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=kuid_t) for example).

Either access it directly from your `kuid_t` variable, or use [`__kuid_val`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__kuid_val) from that same header.

Comment: Yep , it worked , header file name is actually "uidgid.h" not "uidgui.h" , after including this header i was able to get user id by : **get_current_user()->uid.val** Thanks for quick reply

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the typo.